# Recovering a Password on FileVault2 Encrypted Mac

Tags: macos, filevault

I changed my admin (login) password on my Macbook Air and subsequently forgot it. The disk is encrypted using FileVault 2. And the resetpassword command in the terminal did not show any disks available to reset the password. Futhermore, the fdesetup command is not found when did a simple 'man fdesetup' command in the terminal. I remember all but the last 3 or 4 characters of the password. A brute force solution might not take too long. But I prefer not to go down this route if this can be solved another way. I also strongly prefer to solve this without going to the Genius Bar. Anyone know how to gain re-entry?

Answer (score 1):

If it would be that easy to restore or find your password FileVault would completely miss its major objective: safely encrypt your data/volume.

---

Booting to Recovery Mode and after opening Terminal in the menubar -> Utilities enter

```
filevaultrecovery
```

The app "Reset Password" will open in the background.

If you saved your password in iCloud choose the first radio button (I forgot my password) and continue resetting your password.

[Alternatively](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204837) you may use your recovery key (if you saved it somewhere) or the password of a second account on your Mac.

To use the recovery key enter in Terminal:

```
#get the lvUUID
diskuitl cs list
#unlock volume with recovery key
diskutil cs unlockVolume lvUUID -passphrase recoverykey
```

An example recovery key looks like this: *35AJ-AC98-TI1H-N4M3-HDUQ-UQFG*

After unlocking the volume you may reset your password.

Comment: I attempted your method. My pass was not saved in iCloud and the only other account is the Guest user account, which has no pass. I don't have a recovery key, it appears. Unless it is the same as my iCloud pass. Would the Genius Bar be able to do anything I can't from the terminal methods?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment about having no recorery key or icloud saved key, there is no way to get the data.